Fantasy TV show name search: a witch, wizard, an archer and an arrow of light
When I was a kid, between 2000 and 2004, there was a show on television, kind of nordic themed, about this young guy, and a witch - a good one - that were attempting to defeat the forces of darkness. The archetypical bad guy, a wizard, had some kind of orb that he used to channel his magic.
There is a memorable scene when the witch confronts the wizard and sacrifices her life by immediately being turned into flame and 'dying' at the ministrations of the evil wizard.
There was also an arrow of light, the young fellow needed to get hold of to defeat the bad guy.
The soundtrack sounded a bit like some of celtic music by Mike Oldfield.
This was not an animation.
Does anyone have an inkling about what I am talking about? I can't remember for the life of me what it was called.

I should add, it was not an animation.

It is better to edit quesion than leaving it as comment

I found it!! After 2 years of searching: The Legend of William Tell




Celtic music by Mike Oldfield? An arrow? In my book it's mean Robin of Sherwood. 



http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086791/
